# Can't get or upgrade dependencies for Flutter in Android Studio

Tags: flutter, dependencies

I'm very new to developing so I'm sorry if this is a silly question. When trying to open a Flutter package from Git I am not able to 'get dependencies' or 'upgrade dependencies'
I get the message:
C:\Flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat --no-color pub get

This is the folder that I installed Flutter in on my computer. I have read other threads here and tried to following with no luck:
- Uninstalled and reinstalled Flutter
- Checked the Flutter SDK setup in 'Languages & Frameworks'
- Tried Flutter Clean
- Check for updates for Flutter

As I said I'm pretty new so may be making a simple mistake. If anyone has any ideas it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running this from your terminal in your project

```
flutter packages get
```

Comment: Yes I tried this too but have not had any success it still won't work

Comment: please post your pubspec.yaml file in text form not a picture

Comment: This is a silly question but how can I post in text form?

Comment: please still post your pubspec.yaml file that error is specific to something being wrong with that file i read your other comments I understand that you got it from a tutorial but that file is very easy to mess up. edit your original post and copy and paste the entire file up there make sure to put it between  ``` on each side

Answer (score 0):

please check indentation in `pubspec.yaml` file while you are writing any package name

Comment: Thanks Jamil I checked it and it looks good - 2 spaces between each. Plus it's a file from a tutorial from Google so I'm hoping they set it up properly

Comment: Happy that you have resolved your issue with my answer

Comment: Sorry Jaimil I didn't solve the problem. When I said it looked good I meant the pusbspec.yaml looked fine and it wasn't the problem. I am still having the issue. Sorry I didn't word that well

Comment: have you setup your dart sdk path?